# Query regarding formation of SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a huge table containing data of the form given below:

```
Id Col1  Col2      Col3
------------------------
a Fruit1 vitaminA vitaminB 
b a      price       "30"
```

Now I want to retrieve all fruits containing vitaminA and vitaminB having price less than 30 in SQL. here 'a' is the id which is given to Fruit1. Fruit1 contains VitaminA and vitaminB. Now, the next row indicates that id 'a' has price 30.

My intent is to retrieve all fruits having vitaminA and vitaminB and having price less than 30. Is there a way in SQL by which I may answer this query?

Comment: What a horrible "schema".  Can you please give a few more rows so we can understand how to separate the "header" rows which indicate the entities from the "attribute" rows which represent that attributes and whether there are other attributes to be ignored, etc?

Comment: Wow. SQL tables are *not* spreadsheets. In particular, they have no inherent ordering, so headers make absolutely no sense. This is really, really bad design that will cause you lots of hassle and frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a join for this:

```
select t.col1
from t join
     t tprice
     on t.id = tprice.col1 and
        tprice.col2 = 'price'
where ((t.col2 = 'VitaminA' and t.col3 = 'VitaminB') or
       (t.col2 = 'VitaminB' and t.col3 = 'VitaminA')
      ) and
      (cast(tprice.col3 as int) <= 30)
```

This is a very arcane data structure.  Can you explain where it comes from?

Comment: @user1778824 . . . This is standard SQL syntax and should basically work in any database.

Comment: @user1778824 . . . Well, in that case, you couldn't compare it to "30".  You could compare it to something else, though.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a self-join on your table to get the result.

```
select t1.id
from yourtable t1
inner join yourtable t2
  on t1.id = t2.col1
where 
(
  t1.col2 = 'vitaminA' and t1.col3 = 'vitaminB'
  or t1.col2 = 'vitaminB' and t1.col3 = 'vitaminA'
)
  and t2.col2 = 'price'
  and cast(t2.col3 as int) < '30';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3f4c8/30)

Or you can use a `WHERE` clause using `EXISTS`:

```
select t1.id
from yourtable t1
where 
(
  t1.col2 = 'vitaminA' and t1.col3 = 'vitaminB'
  or t1.col2 = 'vitaminB' and t1.col3 = 'vitaminA'
)
  and exists (select t2.col1
              from yourtable t2
              where t2.col2 = 'price'
                and cast(t2.col3 as int) < 30
                and t1.id = t2.col1)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/3f4c8/31)

As a side note, your current data structure is very difficult to work with. If possible you might want to consider restructuring your tables.

Comment: @user1778824 it would work if you were comparing data that was a date. 30 is not a date value so you cannot compare that to a date.